# How to use bootstrap tooltip when mouseover image

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have my jQuery code which creates the **`image`** and **`li`** element dynamically on the fly. I want to use bootstrap tooltip so that when my mouse is over that image, details of that image should be displayed in a separate tooltip like a pop-up but using bootstrap tooltip. However am unable to figure out where am going wrong . Here is my code :

```
   $.ajax({
            url: "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?apikey=XXXXXXXX&q=" + name + "&page_limit=5",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (response) {
                $(".display-movie").empty();
                var ul = $(".display-movie");
                console.log(response);
                for (var i = 0; i < response.movies.length; i++) {

                    var astart = $("<a>").attr("href", "#")
                                     .attr("rel", "tooltip")
                                     .append(img);
                    var img = $("<img>").attr("src", response.movies[i].posters.thumbnail)
                                        .css({
                                            width: 200,
                                            height: 200,
                                            margin: 20
                                        }).mouseover(function () {
                                            $("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip();
                                        })
                                          .append(aend);

                    var aend = $("</a>");
                    var div = $("<div></div>")
                        .append(astart)
                        .append(response.movies[i].title);
                    $("<li></li>")
                        .append(div)
                        .appendTo(ul);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: You did not seem to learn from your other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You could use delegation**

```
var $movieDisplay = $(".display-movie");
$movieDisplay.tooltip({
  selector: '[rel=tooltip]'
});

$.ajax({
  url: 'http://host.tld',
  success: function(response) {
    // Use $movieDisplay here to avoid selecting it over and over again
    $movieDisplay.empty();
    ...
  }
});
```

**Advantages:**

- Less event listeners, better performance
- Every element in `$movieDisplay` with `rel='tooltip'` will show a tooltip regardless if it was created after or before the `tooltip(options)` call

**See it in action:**

http://jsfiddle.net/marionebl/P6XK5/1/

Comment: Why did you create the variable `var $movieDisplay = $(".display-movie");` if you were just going to use the same thing on the next line? Just make it `$(".display-movie").tooltip({...`.

Comment: `$movieDisplay` could (and should!) be used in the callback for the `$.ajax` call. Made this clearer by adding some lines of the callback.

Answer (score 1):

You append element in wrong way. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?apikey=48fv438wmjsh44bqutgd3gzn&q=" + name + "&page_limit=5",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(response) {
        $(".display-movie").empty();
        var ul = $(".display-movie");
        var ul_string = '';
        console.log(response);
        for (var i = 0; i < response.movies.length; i++) {
            ul_string +=
                '<li>' +
                    '<div>' +
                        '<a href="#" rel="tooltip">' +
                            '<img src="' + response.movies[i].posters.thumbnail + '" />' +
                        '</a>' +
                        response.movies[i].title +
                    '</div>' +
                '</li>';
        }

        ul.append(ul_string);
        ul.find('img').css({
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
            margin: 20
        });
        ul.find('[rel="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    }
});
```